# How do I make shapes/objects in pygame?

Tags: python, object, pygame

I wan't to know how I can make objects in pygame. For example a Rectangle. How do I draw it? And I know/heard that you need different names for different shapes for example rect for rectangle. Can you tell me wich names I should use for other shapes? For example a triangle or a circle, etc.

I really hope this question is fitting to StackOverflow and not a waste of time for you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can draw `rectangle` in `pygame` using this code line -

```
DISPLAY=pygame.display.set_mode((500,400),0,32)
pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAY,BLUE,(200,150,100,50))
```

The above code, creates a rectangle Blue in color.

Now, Let's say in future you want to make a rectangle smaller or larger, in that case, you can just remove this rectangle and redraw it using the above command.

Similarly, to draw `circle` , you can use something like this:-

```
pygame.draw.circle(DISPLAY, BLUE, (150, 50), 15, 1)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can I -for example- draw a triangle or circle?

Comment: Updated my answer to show how to draw circle.

Comment: Ok, can you -if it isn't to much- tell me how to make all the other shapes? It would be a huuuge help :)

Comment: So, you can draw a whole lot of shapes using the many inbuilt methods of pygame. You can DM me and I can help :)

Comment: Well, if there is a website already please tell me and maybe then I don't have to bother you anymore :)